# How to sync sidekiq logs to cloudwatch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-cloudwatch, sidekiq

Not sure since which version, but sidekiq no longer support logging to a specific file, but only to stdout or to system log.
as part of my rails application, which also uses sidekiq, I want to sync these sideiq logs to cloudwatch.

Currently, due to their change, all the logs go to /var/syslog, along with other "junk" from other processes. how do I sync the sidekiq logs with cloudwatch? I could not find a clear answer, appreciate some help!

Thanks